# In python s[:1] first one is ignored but s[:3] in this the third alphabet is included? s is a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why in python while slicing a string suppose `s='hello'` we run command `s[1:]` and the result is 'ello'.First alphabet is ignored.But `s[:3]` gives result `'hel'`. 3rd alphabet should be ignored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: When you specify `a[i:j]` it is always **`i` included**, and **`j` excluded**.

Answer (score 1):

This is slicing notation. The first index is *included*, and the last index is *excluded*.

When you do `[1:]`, the first letter isn't ignored. The first letter has an index of 0, so you literally told the notation to *include everything from the second letter to the end*. When you do `[:3]`, the indices 0, 1, and 2 (corresponding to h, e, l) are included. The fourth letter (index 3) is not included.